# AttributeError: module 'main.views' has no attribute 'home'

Tags: python, django

I'm making a django project and whenever I run "python manage.py runserver". I see the above error.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import ToDoList, Item

# Create your views here.

def index(response, id):
    ls = ToDoList.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(response, "main/base.html", {})

def home(response):
    return render(response, "main/home.html", {})
```

main/url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from main import views
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
path("<int:id>", views.index, name="index"),
path("", views.home, name="home")
]
```

mysite/url.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("main.urls")),
]
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: seems like an indentation error, the `home(...)` must be at the ***root level***, not inside the `index(...)` function

Comment: What directory is `views.py` in?  Is it in `main/` ?

Comment: @Gordon Yes it's in main/.

Comment: Please show the whole traceback, and label each file with the app it is in.

Comment: Some time its just due to migrations not done. so just do `python manage.py migration`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from main import views
from . import views
```

Those last two imports both import the name `views`, so the first one is overwritten by the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Your `home` function is indented wrongly, it's currently a function *inside* the `index` function, not in the global scope.

Change it to the following

`views.py`

```py
def index(response, id):
      ls = ToDoList.objects.get(id=id)
      return render(response, "main/base.html", {})

def home(response): # Don't indent this!
    return render(response, "main/home.html", {})
```

Comment: sorry for that. I edited that. It's not indented wrongly. It was a type error in the question not the code. The home function is not inside the index function.I apologize for the type error

Answer (score 0):

There must be a configuration issue but if you want to see if website is working or def Home(): is working. Change your code to

```
def home(request):
return HttpResponse('<h1>Blog Home</h1>')
```

Comment: you missed indentation!

Answer (score 0):

have you added the app in the INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py ?